# How does Cordova handle browser-specific tasks?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am developing web apps in HTML, CSS and JavaScript, and then I am willing to compile them into android apps using PhoneGap Cordova. I am stuck with the idea of how Cordova handles browser-specific tasks such as local storage. Moreover, I have no access to local files using javascript. Will I be able to access local files after I compile my web app into an android app?

Comment: If you use cordova plugins, the plugin will use the native Code of the Android/iOS device.

Comment: Yeah got it. Thanks alot @Mazz!

Comment: You may wanna accept my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use cordova plugins, the plugin will use the native Code of the Android/iOS device.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to the above answer. Local storage works in the same way as you would use it in the browser.

```
localStorage.setItem('key', 'value');

localStorage.getItem('key');
```

To access the native file system use the Cordova file plugin here.

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/

The samples in the documentation will help.